# How can I use underscores in "LIKE" conditions in Tivoli?

Tags: sql, tivoli

I can't properly use underscores in the `LIKE` part when I use Tivoli databases.

I connected to a Tivoli database with [AQT](http://www.querytool.com/) and just run this query;

```
select NODE_NAME from NODES where NODE_NAME like '%_SQL'
```

This query gets as result;

```
AKHEDEFSRV_SQL
AKHEDEF_SQL
AKLSFS_SQLPAKL1_SQL
AKLSFS_SQLPAKL2_SQL
```

But also gets

```
AKLSPRODSQL
AKLSTESTSQL
```

It looks to me as if Tivoli ignores the underscore in the `LIKE` part of the query. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underscore matches a single character, unless it is escaped.  Try:

```
select NODE_NAME from NODES where NODE_NAME like '%__SQL' escape '_'
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Try the double underscore in my edit...

Comment: Yep, that's right. The weird part is there is no even document to use this underscore in `LIKE` part of the query, maybe at least I can't find online.. Thanks!